# Change View Controller Image from another View Controller Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Can you please tell me how to change UIImageView's Image in ViewController A from View Controller B?

My Xcode version is Xcode 7, with Swift 2.0,

Thank you.

Comment: You can use an NSNotification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [thefredelement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4096655/thefredelement) you can use `NSNotification` for that like in your ViewController B just add this code when you are dismissing view to ViewController A:

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in your viewController A add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshList:", name:"refresh", object: nil)
}
```

And add this helper method in same class:

```
func refreshList(notification: NSNotification){

    println("parent method is called")
    //you can change your UIImageView's Image here.

}
```

Now when ever you press button from ViewController B it will call this method from ViewController A.

Note: I have tested this with Xcode 6.4 and I think it will work fine with Xcode 7 too.

Comment: One more question, How do I save the setting of the wallpaper?

Comment: So after I change the background image, how do I save the data that it will stay on that image using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: what if the second file is not a view controller but a swift file holding common functions such as ui image picker and image cropper etc...

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4

1st View Controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!  // ImageView 

func goToImageChooserClass () {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
    secondVC.firstVC = self // Object in 2nd Controller that is a FirstVC Object
    self.present(secondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)

}
```

2nd View Controller

```
class SecondVC {
    ...
    var firstVC:FirstVC! // Object representing the firstVC
    ...
    func goBack (){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        self.firstVC.imageView = {insert your image here}
        })   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is how you work with `NSUserDefaults`

You write like this :

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setObject(image!, forKey: "image")
```

and read like this :

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let image = defaults.objectForKey("image") as! UIImage
```

and set it to the `imageView`

Comment: Why have you added this answer? It is not even partially related to the question, you haven't formatted the code and you have bumped a question that is over a year old and it already has an accepted answer. Don't do this.

Comment: And it's a bad solution. Saving an image to disk just to be able to fetch it in another view is... not optimal, to be polite.